# Calculate radius of curve/arc formed by line segments (approximate)

Tags: math, game-physics, curve

The calculation is for games so a approximation is better than a computational intense correct calculation. What i need to find is the radius of the given arc.

In this case the "curve" can be thought of a arc as this approximation is good enough. So the situation look like this:

[image]

**I know:**

1. the length the green lines (which are equal)
2. the length of the blue arc
3. the value of α in degrees

**What i need to know:**

- the radius r

**Background - Actually i need the radius for two things:**

1. To calculate the length of a arc `B` with offset of `x` from the center arc. So that r of `B` would be `r + x`
2. To calculate the centrifugal force of a vehicle driving on that curve

**What i tried:**

I know how to calculate the radius if i have the circumference and the inner angle of the arc. But i am completely stuck with the given information though i am sure it should not be too complicated ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think a triangle with right angle at the middle of the green line and another point at the center of the circle, then the angle at the intersection of the green segments in that triangle is α/2 and the cosine ratio for that angle is

```
cos(α/2)*r = g/2
```

g the length of a green segment.

---

The angle at the top of a pie slice is `π-α` so that for the length `b` of the blue curve segments you should get

```
b = (π-α)*r
```

The radius values you get from both formulas should not differ more than the measurement errors let expect.

Comment: I am trying to follow at the moment.. So following your first point, am i right that the radius should be `r = (g * 0.5) / cos(α/2)` ?

Comment: Yes. There is also the regression method that transforms the circle equation `(x[k]-cx)^2+(y[k]-cy)^2=r^2` into a linear equation `cx*x[k] + cy*y[k] + 0.5*(r^2-cx^2-cy^2) = 0.5*(x[k]^2+y[k]^2)`, i.e., `a*x[k]+b*y[k]+c=z[k]`, which might give better results if multiple points on or near the circle are given.

Comment: That is interesting. Actually my arc is not an arc but as i said a curve. The α would in my case be the average of the different angles because this simplification will as i think be good enough since the single steps will be small compared to the overall curvature. The "resolution" or length of the green segment can be controlled by me.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use Catmull-Rom (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline), Hermite (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline), or natural (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) cubic spline interpolation to calculate the path between the points.

This will give you cubic polynomials for the (x,y) coordinates, and it's easy to take their 2nd derivatives to get the direction and magnitude of acceleration.

Comment: Actually i am using unreal engines Spline implementation as a core building block. I will definitely have a look how and if i can incorporate your tipps. My goal is to calculate how much more/less distance it is if a am offset `x` from the spline. Calculating the centrifugal force is what i think i will get "for free" if i know the angle.